# Java-Stream - Combine results of two methods producing a Value and a List invoked conditionaly inside the same stream operation in Java 8

Tags: java, list, functional-programming, java-stream

I have two methods: `funca()` and `funcb()` which return a value of type `X` or a `List<X>` respectively like shown below:

```
X funca(Event e) { ... }

List<X> funcb(Event e) { ... }
```

I want to use them in the Stream and collect the result into a list.

These method methods should be called under different conditions, like shown below in pseudocode:

```
List<Event> input = // initializing the input

List<X> resultList = input.values().stream()
    .(event -> event.status=="active" ? funca(event) : funcb(event))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can someone please tell me how I can achieve this so that whether the function returns a list of values or values?

Comment: If that is literally your code, are you sure `event.status == "active"` is the correct way to do string comparison? perhaps use `.equals()` ?

Comment: Also create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks @whiplash, This is not the actual code. I just made something out to convey what the issue was. You sure are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since one of your functions produces a Collection as a result, you need a stream operation that allows performing *one-to-many* transformation. For now, Stream IPA offers two possibilities: `flatMap()` and `mapMulti()`.

To approach the problem, you need to take a closer look at them and think in terms of these operations.

### [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function))

This operation requires a function producing a `Stream`, and elements of this new stream become a replacement for the initial element.

Therefore, you need to wrap the result returned by the `funca()` with Singleton-Stream using `Stream.of()` (*there's **no need** for wrapping the element with a* `List`*, like shown in another answer* `flatMap()` *is **not capable** to consume Collections*).

```
List<X> = input.values().stream()
    .flatMap(event -> "active".equals(event.getStatus()) ? 
        Stream.of(funca(event)) : funcb(event).stream()
    )
    .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList())
```

### [`mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer))

This operation was introduced with Java 16 and is similar to `flatMap()` but acts differently.

Contrary to `flatMap` it doesn't consume a new Stream. As an argument it expects a `BiConsumer`. Which in turn takes a stream element and a `Consumer` of the resulting type. Every element offered to the `Consumer` becomes a part of the resulting stream.

`mapMulti()` might be handy if `funcb()` produces a list which is very moderate in size (refer to documentation linked above for more details), otherwise `flatMap()` would be the right tool.

```
List<X> = input.values().stream()
    .<X>mapMulti((event, consumer) -> {
        if ("active".equals(event.getStatus())) consumer.accept(funca(event));
        else funcb(event).forEach(consumer);
    })
    .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList())
```

---

***Sidenote:** don't use `==` to compare reference types (like* `String`*) unless you need to make sure that both references are pointing to the same object, use* `equals()` *method instead.*

Answer (score 1):

Embed the result of `funcA` into a list and `flatMap` the lists:

```
List<X> result = input.stream()
                      .flatMap(e -> e.status.equals("active") ? List.of(funcA(e)) : funcB(e))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```